# window closes after Method ends

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm working on a WPF-project in Visual Studio 2017 for the company I'm working at, and I've encountered a bug that I just can't make any sense of...

Here's the problem:
The app is for changing and retrieving information regarding lockers for our workers (many people come and go, so there's a lot of changes every day)
So the app opens with a MainWindow (obviously) that contains a list (DataGrid) of all existing lockers and some of the most inportant information about them.

To change anything about the Locker (Emptying it, changing status ect.) you can doubleklick an entry to open another window with all details about the chosen Locker. So far so good!

The problem arises when I try to save the details and close the window, because it doesn't get to my SaveData method. it needs to go through a few methods before saving but it seems to just end after a specific method (addHistory) ends. Without even getting to SaveData.

Code:

```
public void AddHistory(Locker l) //[2.1.2.0]
{
    Debug("AddHistory() Start [2.1.2.0]");
    History h = new History();
    h.HistID = hID;
    hID++;
    h.LockerNum = l.Nr;
    h.Vis = visPop;
    h.LockerID = l.ID;
    h.TnFrstNameHist = l.TnFrstName;
    h.TnNameHist = l.TnName;
    h.FullName = l.TnName + " " + l.TnFrstName;
    h.Date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    h.Time = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    Debug("Before GetAction() [2.1.2.0]");
    h.ActionTaken = GetAction();
    if (h.ActionTaken == "")
    {
        h.ActionTaken = "Keine";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < allLoc.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (l.ID == allLoc[i].ID)
        {
            allLoc[i].LocHist.Add(h);
            historyList.Add(h);
            if (allLoc[i].LocHist[0].ActionTaken == "Keine" || allLoc[i].LocHist[0].ActionTaken == "none")
                {
                    allLoc[i].LocHist.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                changedHist = allLoc[i].LocHist;
                DataGridHist.Items.Clear();
                foreach (History his in changedHist)
                {
                    DataGridHist.Items.Add(his);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).SaveData();

        Debug("AddHistory() End [2.1.2.0]");
    }

    public string GetAction() //[2.1.2.1]
    {
        Debug("GetAction Start [2.1.2.1]");
        string histOut = "";

        //loc.Nr throws up a reference exception!

        if (checkLoc.Nr != locker.Nr)
        {
            histOut = "GarderobenNummer Geändert";
        }

        if (checkLoc.SecKey != locker.SecKey)
        {
            if (locker.SecKey == true)
            {
                histOut = "Ersatzschlüssel Herausgegeben";
            }
            else
            {
                histOut = "Ersatzschlüssel zurück erhalten";
            }
        }

        if (checkLoc.Status != locker.Status)
        {
            if (checkLoc.Status == statusArr[3])
            {
                histOut = "Kontrolliert";
            }
            else if (checkLoc.Status == statusArr[4])
            {
                histOut = "Schloss Ausgetauscht";
            }
            else if (checkLoc.Status == statusArr[2])
            {
                histOut = "Vorbereitet für neue Teilnehmer";
            }
        }

        Debug("GetAction() End [2.1.2.1]");

        return histOut;
    }

private void Save_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //[2.2.0.1]
    {
        if (IsLockerChanged())
        {
            //Make Pop-up with field to enter a visum.

            NamePopUp visPop = new NamePopUp();
            visPop.ShowDialog();

            //Save the data and close the window.

            if (visCheck == true)
            {
                Debug("Before AddHistory() [2.2.0.1]");
                AddHistory(locker);
                Debug("After AddHistory() [2.2.0.1]");
                foreach(Locker l in mw.lockerList)
                {
                    if(l.ID == locker.ID)
                    {
                        Debug("Locker Found in Loop [2.2.0.1]");
                        l.Nr = locker.Nr;
                        l.TnName = locker.TnName;
                        l.TnFrstName = locker.TnFrstName;
                        l.TnWorkingGroup = locker.TnWorkingGroup;
                        l.Status = locker.Status;
                        l.SecKey = locker.SecKey;
                        l.LocHist = locker.LocHist;
                        Debug("Locker in loop copied [2.2.0.1]");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                Debug("Before SaveData() [2.2.0.1]");
                mw.SaveData();
                Debug("After SaveData() [2.2.0.1]");
                checkLoc.Nr = locker.Nr;
                checkLoc.TnName = locker.TnName;
                checkLoc.TnFrstName = locker.TnFrstName;
                checkLoc.TnWorkingGroup = locker.TnWorkingGroup;
                checkLoc.Status = locker.Status;
                checkLoc.SecKey = locker.SecKey;
                checkLoc.LocHist = locker.LocHist;

                visCheck = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Msg("Es wurden keine Änderungen gefunden.");
        }
    }
```

Debug is a method to output info while debugging, it's basically just a MessageBox.Show().

The output that i get when i try to test it is:

```
Before AddHistory() [2.2.0.1]    
AddHistory() Start [2.1.2.0]    
Before GetAction() [2.1.2.0]    
GetAction Start [2.1.2.1]    
GetAction() End [2.1.2.1]    
AddHistory() End [2.1.2.0]
```

After that, the window just closes....

I've already tried cleaning the code and rebuilding it, but the result stays the same.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause such a problem and/or how I can fix it?

If you need more information, just ask!

Thanks in advance!

As requested Here's the Code for the SaveData() Method:

```
public void SaveData(int id = -1)
    {
        if(isDebug && id != -1)
        {
            string output = "";
            foreach(Locker l in lockerList)
            {
                if(l.ID == id)
                {
                    output += "ID: " + l.ID + "\r\n";
                    output += "Nr: " + l.Nr + "\r\n";
                    output += "Room: " + l.Room + "\r\n";
                    output += "RoomName: " + l.RoomName + "\r\n";
                    output += "Seckey: " + l.SecKey + "\r\n";
                    output += "Status: " + l.Status + "\r\n";
                    output += "FrstName: " + l.TnFrstName + "\r\n";
                    output += "Name: " + l.TnName + "\r\n";
                    output += "WorkingGroup: " + l.TnWorkingGroup;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Debug(output);
        }

        string fp = saveFile; //The used Filepath

        if (!Directory.Exists(savePath)) //Check if the directory in AppData exists
        {
            //Directory doesn't exist
            Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath); //Create the directory 
        }

        //prepate to create or open a file
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream fs;

        if (!File.Exists(fp)) //Check if there is a file
        {
            //No File
            fs = File.Create(fp); //Create a File
            FillEmptyData();
        }
        else
        {
            //File Exists
            fs = File.Open(fp, FileMode.Open); //Open the File
        }

        DefineSaveData();

        bf.Serialize(fs, saveData); //save the Locker Data into the file.
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to answer it. Have you tried to debug your app?

Comment: Can you show `SaveData` ?

Comment: What happens when you set a breakpoint at `Debug("After AddHistory() [2.2.0.1]");` ? What's happening after that ?

Comment: also why are you calling `mw.SaveData();` and `(Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).SaveData();` in the same execution ?

Comment: The SaveData Code wouldn't help you, since i know that it works (tested it in other parts of the app) The problem is that the code just stops executing after AddHistory, so it doesn't even get to the foreach-loop. I'll try with the breaking point and will get back with the results in a few minutes and about the two way's to execute the SaveData is just that i wrote (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).SaveData() first and noticed after a while that the it's easier to reference the window and execute it that way.

Comment: Adding a breaking point doesn't change anything... and I'll add the SaveData Code to the Original post, since i really have no idea where the problem lies...